# Changing menu items on a toolbar menu made from a xml layout

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar

So I have this toolbar in my app, and I want to display different menu items depending on whether the user is logged in or not. When the user logs in or out I want to update my layout which for now is the toolbar menu to represent the change. For some reason though, my menu items are not removed at all, all of them are visible at all times, regardless of the login state.

My menu items:

```
<menu
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logged_out"
        android:title="@string/action_log_in"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logged_in"
        android:title="@string/action_log_out"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

The first menu item is only supposed to be visible to a user that is logged in. Also I guess it's self explanatory but I only want one of the log in/out buttons to be visible depending on the login state.

My Java code:

```
protected void initializeToolbar(){
    myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    menu = myToolbar.getMenu();
    resetToolbarMenu();
    myToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}

private void resetToolbarMenu(){
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    if(loginPrefs.getBoolean("login", false)) { //loginPrefs is reference to a SharedPreference object
        menu.removeItem(1);
    } else {
        menu.removeItem(2);
        menu.removeItem(0);
    }
}
```

Reason I got two methods is that I only want to set up the toolbar and listener once, but I want to be able to change the menu every time the user logs in/out without reloading the page.

After a successful login the `resetToolbarMenu()` method will be called again.

I suppose the `menu.remove(0)` does not update the UI, but I could not find another way to reach my menu object without first inflating it and then getting it from the toolbar, and I assume the inflation is what decides what items are visible. Basically, I could not find a way to remove any menu items before inflating or updating the UI in another way than inflating.

**Solution**:

I changed my java code into something like this:

```
protected void initializeToolbar(){
    myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // Don't know if this is necessary or if returning true is prefered.
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(loginPrefs.getBoolean("login", false)) {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
        menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I also had to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on logout/login to update the toolbar/menu. However onPrepareOptionsMenu() is also automatically called whenever you open the menu for items that aren't shown on the toolbar itself.

PS: `OnCreateOptionsMenu` and `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` will not be used unless you remember to `setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)` as I forgot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create options menu by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu`. You can create 2 xml and inflate either one of them depending on your logic. To force a redraw of the menu, you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu`.

For example

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if (login) {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
    } else {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.logout_menu, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And outside change the flag and force redraw

```
login = false; // or true
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: I'm looking for something more dynamic than statically defining two layouts. If I'm already in the activity for adding new stuff I don't want to show the add item either, which would make it 4 different xml files instead of 2. Definitely gonna check this OptionsMenu thing though.

Comment: Same approach for dynamic menu. You need to create the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu using menu.add instead of inflating a static layout. And force a redraw using invalidateOptionsMenu

Comment: Hmm. That would force me to define the menu items programatically it seems? Is there no way to load the xml menu as an object and then inflate by using that object after using menu.remove(int)?

Comment: From what I understand from your initial requirement, you just want to hide/show the menu items depending on some state. If you want your menus to be static, define a layout. If not, create your menu items individually. Both of them are performed in onCreateOptionsMenu. If you want to modify the properties of your menu items before displaying them, override onPrepareOptionsMenu. After that, your menu will be visible. The proper way to update the menu is to force a reload and it will call the 2 methods again.

Comment: So I got it all working. I was able to utilize the visible fields of all the menu items, thus not having to make it more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override [onPrepareOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) in the activity to change the items in the menu.

From the documentation:

Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

Comment: So I would move my code for removing items into this method and then the items will be prepared properly every time I try to inflate the menu? Or do I use the invalidateOptionsMenu method from the other answer to force this method to run? Documentation does not give confused people any examples :/

Comment: This method is always called, you don't have to invalidate. If you use invalidate, you force it to call onCreateOptionsMenu again. You should use invalidateOptionsMenu if you want to inflate another one, like a completely different xml, if you just want to remove some items, do it on onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: So I got it all working. But onPrepareOptionsMenu was only called whenever I pressed something on the toolbar/menu. In order to update it when I logged in/out I used invalidateOptionsMenu. Maybe there's a better way to force the prepare method without calling the create method again, but for now invalidate seems to do it for me.